# Error al activar Apache después de agregar virtualhost

Tags: apache, xampp, virtualhost

escribo aquí ya que tengo un problema después de agregar virtualhost.

Resulta que tengo una página web de Wordpress hecha en localhost y para no tener que poner toda la IP siempre, oí hablar de virtualhost, resulta que después de agregar este, al ingresar a mi página de Wordpress no me dejaba con la nueva configuración ya que **al volver a iniciar el proceso de Apache me ponía que se cerró inesperadamente**.

Total que después de lo que me pasó, decidí dejarlo como estaba (sin el virtualhost) pero resulta que ahora al volver a ponerlo como estaba ya no me muestra mi página Web porque me sigue poniendo que Apache se cerró inesperadamente y estoy nervioso ya que es un proyecto que tengo que entregarlo muy pronto y volver a hacerla me costaría muchísimo tiempo.

**Todo esto lo estoy haciendo desde Windows 10.**

Comment: indica las configuraciones que cambiaste

Comment: en windows o linux?

Comment: Es en Windows, ahora pasaré captura de lo que he cmabiado:

Comment: Lo primero que hice fue descomentar  la opción VirtualHosts en Apache (httpd.conf), después de eso fui al archivo donde se configuran los virtualhost (httpd-vhost.conf) en el apache/conf/extra. Lo que puse en ese archivo fue: <VirtualHost *:80>
       DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/proyecto/wordpress/"
       ServerName wordpress.localhost
</VirtualHost>Por último fui a C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts y agregué el dominio personalizado aquí. Después de esto vi que no funcionaba y ya ahí es cuando fue todo mal, después de esto lo puse todo como estaba y al dia de hoy sigue sin funcionar